# what's the difference between the HMAC signature and hashing directly?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, hmac

Just out of curiosity, really... for example, in python,

```
hashlib.sha1("key" + "data").hexdigest() != hmac.new("key", "data", hashlib.sha1)
```

is there some logical distinction I'm missing between the two actions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac

Comment: yes, first one insecure, second one secure

Answer (score 4):

hashlib.sha1 gives you simply sha1 hash of content "keydata" that you give as a parameter (note that you are simply concatenating the two strings). The hmac call gives you keyed hash of the string "data" using string "key" as the key and sha1 as the hash function. The fundamental difference between the two calls are that the HMAC can only be reproduced if you know the key so you would also know something about who has generated the hmac. SHA1 can only be used to detect that content has not changed.

Comment: arguably, you would have a tough time (assuming secure hash function etc. etc.) generating the same digest if you did not have access to the key... Basically, @mouad above gave me the guide to work out for myself and the answer is key padding. I'd like to accept an answer, but I may well have to answer it myself.

Comment: @Ben: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac#Design_principles explains some of the reasons your original idea is bad.  But the basic rule is very simple: Never, ever invent your own cryptography.

Comment: @Nemo, I hope I never suggested that I was intending to invent my own crypto, nor was my question "an idea" for a "better" "way" of doing anything. I was asking, out of my irrepressibly curious nature, what it was that made HMAC different from concatenation and hashing.

Comment: @Ben: Fair enough.  It was your comment here more than the original question that made me wonder.  (Plus it is a very common tendency, even among people who are otherwise experts.)  It is a fine question; sorry for over reading.

Comment: @Nemo, no worries. I've read plenty of questions here where someone does seem to believe there's a reason for their reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the manual.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac#Design_principles